# How do I check if this code exists in a variable

Tags: php, curl

I am looking at a CURL result from Google in PHP which now will sometimes result in a redirect using this format:

```
 Please click <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=site:test.com//&gbv=1&sei=vGn6UobNMaqssQTo4IHoDA">here</a> if you are not redirected
```

How can I check if this is in the variable called $result and then get the URL in the link href using PHP?

Comment: I doubt you are allowed to do that, but either way use `DOMDocument` to parse the contents.

Comment: `if($var1 == $var2){ // do something }`

Comment: This is rate limit by Google and will eventually also include a captcha to complete. You need to set referer headers from the original result URL. It will soon be more complex than you think. They do this for the exact purpose of blocking scripts like yours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(isset($result )){
    $url = preg_replace('/.*Please click <a href="([^"]*)".*/', "$1", $result );
    print $url;
}
```

Or

```
if(isset($result ) && preg_match('/Please click <a href="([^"]*)"/', $result, $m )){
    print $m[1];
}
```

Comment: It is not parsing a whole html page. Just few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DomDocument` to parse the HTML and extract the url. Please note that if you are using the script contrary to the ToS of the server that you are requesting data from, it can have legal and financial consequences.

I am using `strpos` to quickly check for a hint that I *need* to parse the page before I commit the resources.

```
if (strpos($result, 'if you are not redirected') !== false) {   

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($result);
    $newUrl = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');

    // new request using $newUrl
}
```

**Documentation**

- `strpos` - http://php.net/strpos
- `DomDocument` - http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php
- `DomElement` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php
- `DomElement::getAttribute` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php